# What guarantees re-rendering in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

In React, changes to local variables do not guarantee a component (which uses that local variable) re-rendering. Only changes in props or state or context (AFAIK) would guarantee re-rendering.

Is it the same case for Svelte, that is, one must use a proper store to guarantee a re-rendering?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every [assignment](https://svelte.dev/docs#component-format-script-2-assignments-are-reactive) to a locally declared variable triggers re-rendering, not just stores.

That is why you need to do something like:

```js
let arr = [];
onMount(() => {
    arr.push(1);
    // A rerender will not be scheduled yet
    arr = arr;
    // Just now, the statement itself will be compiled away, but the runtime will know
});
```

To guarantee a re-render has been executed before continiuing you can use [await tick()](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-tick).